# Predicting if a query will use a cached plan

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that doesn't seem to cause or use an entry in the procedure cache but when I look at stats I can't see evidence of any resources being spent on parsing etc.

My questions are:

- Is there any method that I can use that can predict if a cached plan would be used at execution time?
- Should I be worried about my query not being cached or should I consider forcing options?
- Is there a reason my query is not being cached?

My query is as follows:

```
set statistics io on 
set statistics time on

select 

ps.permanentpolicyref,
pt.effdate,
pt.donedate,
a.agentref,
a.groupingcode,
pt.transactiontype,
pt.transactionstatus,
pt.BrokerQuoteSystem
from policytransaction pt 

inner join PolicyStatic ps on ps.refno = pt.refno
inner join Policy p on pt.PolicyId = p.PolicyId 
inner join Agents a on p.AgentID = a.AgentId

where 
pt.transactiontype in ('nb', 'ab', 'rb') 
and pt.transactionstatus in ('a', 'p')
and pt.policystatus <> 'd'
--and  a.groupingcode = '79584'
and pt.schemecode in  (45, 47, 48, 49, 50, 53, 54, 56)
and pt.donedate > '2009-12-01'
order by pt.donedate desc
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that a cached plan is not being used? Is your query parameterized?

Comment: Are you asking how to track your query recompiles (Extended Events is the easiest way) or are you asking why your specific query gets recompiled? If you hit F5 twice on exactly same query, the query plan is reused. If you change anything (even add a space), the ad hoc query will be recompiled.

Comment: I have been looking at dm_exec_cached_plans

Comment: My query is not parameterized , I was just looking at how code would travel into the procedure cache . I will do as suggested and run same code twice and see if I can see if I can avoid a recompile. I did expect that the code would enter the procedure cache on the first run and then use the same plan on the second run